# How I change the date for my Australian transit visa?

Tags: australia, transit-visas

I had booked my flight from Auckland to Melbourne for the 10th of July and a connecting flight to India. My Auckland-Melbourne flight has been cancelled I am being offered a flight on the 9th of July instead.

What should I do about my transit visa? I had applied for the 10th of July. Can I change the dates easily?

Comment: Has the visa already been issued? If so, what does it say? If not, have you tried asking the visa application center or the consulate?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear, since the asker was asked to clarify but seems to have abandoned the question.